# What's the difference in content between the Ubuntu and Lubuntu Software Centers? Why aren't winners of the app showdown available in the latter?

Tags: software-center, lubuntu

What's the difference in content between the Ubuntu and Lubuntu Software Centers?

I've seen this [Are softwares installable on ubuntu also installable on lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163162/are-softwares-installable-on-ubuntu-also-installable-on-lubuntu) which indicates that the content should be the same. However, I looked for Ridual, OrthCal, Cuttlefish and MenuLibre. While all four are available in the Ubuntu Software Center, they aren't listed in the Lubuntu Software Center. Will they eventually be listed? Who decides?

I'm asking because one of the criteria in the apps showdown, if I understood correctly, was desktop integration. If by "desktop", **Unity** is specifically implied then it would make sense not including them in the Lubuntu Software Center. Is that correct?

I'm on 12.04.

Comment: " If by "desktop", **Unity** is specifically implied then it would make sense not including them in the Lubuntu Software Center. Is that correct?" Probably, *yes*.

Comment: I had asked about this [elsewhere](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12164393&postcount=2) and at one [respondent](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12218766&postcount=7) was hopeful that there would be something in the code that would allow the software to detect the desktop and modify its behavior accordingly. Obviously, software that fundamentally depends on something unique to Unity won't be able to function in other DEs. In short, I'd expect apps that are totally dependent on Unity to be restricted to USC whereas others could be provided in LSC.

Comment: @vasa1 I see no reason applications that require Unity shouldn't be available to install in the Lubuntu Software Center. What about users (like me) who have both `ubuntu-desktop` and `lubuntu-desktop` installed? (I do think you've [answered it perfectly here](http://askubuntu.com/a/197142/22949), though.)

Comment: @Eliah Kagan, I don't know quite what to say. But it's _possible_ that people using Lubuntu for its "lightness of being", would not want apps that would pull in, in effect, a new desktop environment. Or maybe such apps could be flagged appropriately to inform potential users of the consequences. In any case, I'm assuming that those with both desktops would have access to the USC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lubuntu Software Center will list more apps in future according to Stephen Smally in a response posted [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2012-October/002562.html):

> That's because Lsc is not currently able to show software from other 
>   sources (e.g. the paying software or the ubuntu apps showdown). the
>   new  Lsc will be hopefully be able to replace Usc in every aspect.

**Updated** on 20130304:
In a comment to a post on [Lubuntu's "Official" Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/groups/lubuntu.official/) dated 201300303, [Phill Whiteside](https://launchpad.net/~phillw) had this to say:

> Lubuntu Software Center is currently stalled as there is no developer
>   to take it forward. So... if you know a competent python programmer
>   who would like a project, please get them to get in touch.

(I don't know how to link to comments in Facebook.)

Comment: The date of each comment on Facebook link to a page with just that thread. (Then copy-paste that URL.)

Answer (score 4):

Both distributions use the same repositories. So, software that can be installed on ubuntu can also be installed on Lubuntu ,which means that they have the same software center.

Comment: Please re-read my question. I'm going to edit the title to properly reflect the issue.

Comment: You must see if you have the same repositories first and you must have the same software list to have same applications between the two distributions

Comment: I answered you in general, for your case you may added a repository for one distribution and didn't fro another

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, there is software that it's in the Ubuntu repositories, Ubuntu and Lubuntu share the same repositories, If you use the LSC and search for "X" software you'll get no results, if you then search in the USC you'll get a result, **why**.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Ubuntu software center to Lubuntu by installing "software-center" package from Synaptic.
The Lubuntu software center is a lightweight app written by the Lubuntu team, by design, it doesn't have all the features of the Ubuntu software center.

That said, the app-contest winners don't seem to be in the main Ubuntu repositories.

for example for the "MyAgenda" app I can go to https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1211/
and I have two options to install the app.  I can download the .deb, or I can add the ppa repo, then install the package with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:piotr-zagawa/ma
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install myagenda
```

Comment: "The Lubuntu software center is a lightweight app written by the Lubuntu team, by design, it doesn't have all the features of the Ubuntu software center." Yes, but why is that using the same repositories the Lubuntu Software Center **cant' find the same software** that you can find in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: define the word "find"

Comment: Hmm, if you search for Inkscape in the USC you get results about the Vector Graphic software, if you Search it in the LSC you get "no results found" (that's an example, but there are other software that do the same)